# Этот метод или свойство не может вызываться для значений равных Null.DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void CreateColums()
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("COMPANY_ID", "ID Компании");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("NAME", "Наименование");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("DIRECTOR", "Директор");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("IsNew", String.Empty);    
}

private void ReadSingleRow(DataGridView dgw, IDataRecord record)
{
    dgw.Rows.Add(record.GetInt32(1), record.GetString(2), record.GetString(3), RowState.ModifiedNew);
}

private void RefreshDataGrid(DataGridView dgw)
{
    dgw.Rows.Clear();

    string queryString = $"select *from company";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, db.GetConnection());

    db.openConnection();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        ReadSingleRow(dgw, reader);
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

В таблице Company есть строки null. Не может прочесть их

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнение к ошибке скрин. У кого есть варианты как прочесть строки Null в SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void ReadSingleRow(DataGridView dgw, IDataRecord record)
{
    /*при условии, что выборка идёт по правильным индексам полей
    field index: 0,1,2,3
    select id, company_id, name, director from company
    */
    int company_id = (record.GetValue(1) == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (int)record.GetValue(1);
    string name = (record.GetValue(2) == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : record.GetString(2);
    string director = (record.GetValue(3) == DBNull.Value) ? string.Empty : record.GetString(3);
    dgw.Rows.Add(company_id, name, director, RowState.ModifiedNew);
}
```